# Using std::reference_wrapper as the key in a std::map

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a bunch of objects in a class hierarchy and would like to make a `std::map` using references to those objects as the keys in the map.  Its seems like `std::reference_wrapper` would be exactly what is needed for this, but I can't seem to make it work.  What I've tried so far:

```
class Object { // base class of my hierarchy
    // most details unimportant
public
    virtual bool operator< (const Object &) const;  // comparison operator
};

std::map<std::reference_wrapper<const Object>, int> table;

auto it = table.find(object);

table[object] = 42;

table[object]++
```

However, I always get somewhat obscure errors from the compiler:

```
/usr/include/c++/4.5.3/bits/stl_function.h: In member function ‘bool std::less<_Tp>::operator()(const _Tp&, const _Tp&) const [with _Tp = std::reference_wrapper<const Object>]’:
/usr/include/c++/4.5.3/bits/stl_tree.h:1522:38:   instantiated from ‘std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::iterator std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::find(const _Key&) [with _Key = std::reference_wrapper<const Object>, _Val = std::pair<const std::reference_wrapper<const Object>, int>, _KeyOfValue = std::_Select1st<std::pair<const std::reference_wrapper<const Object>, int> >, _Compare = std::less<std::reference_wrapper<const Object> >, _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const std::reference_wrapper<const Object>, int> >, std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::iterator = std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<const std::reference_wrapper<const Object>, int> >]’
/usr/include/c++/4.5.3/bits/stl_map.h:697:29:   instantiated from ‘std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::iterator std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::find(const key_type&)[with _Key = std::reference_wrapper<const Object>, _Tp = int, _Compare = std::less<std::reference_wrapper<const Object> >, _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const std::reference_wrapper<const Object>, int> >, std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::iterator = std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<const std::reference_wrapper<const Object>, int> >, key_type = std::reference_wrapper<const Object>]’
testfile.cpp:39:31:   instantiated from here
/include/c++/4.5.3/bits/stl_function.h:230:22: error: no match for ‘operator<’ in ‘__x < __y’
```

The error seems to be saying it can't compare two `std::reference_wrapper<const Object>` objects, but it seems like it should be possible -- `std::reference_wrapper` has a conversion operator that can implicitly convert it to a `T&` (`const Object &` here), and `Object` has a `operator <`, so why doesn't it work?

Should it work and this is merely a bug in g++?  Or is something else going on?

Comment: Does `std::ref(object) < std::ref(object)` compile?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems that it would work if you made the comparison operator a free function (that perhaps calls a virtual member function).

If it is a member function, `a < b` really means `a.operator<(b);` and implicit conversions are not considered for the left-side argument.

Comment: Another point in favour of non-member `operator`s where possible, I think? Now that I'm starting to use `reference_wrapper` more, I might have some refactoring to do.

Answer (score 15):

By default [`std::map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) uses `std::less<std::reference_wrapper<const Object>>` as `Compare`, but `std::reference_wrapper<T>` doesn't forward `operator<()` to the underlying type `T`.

The simplest and concisest option to solve your problem is to define `std::less<const Object>` (or `std::greater<const Object>`) in the map definition like this:

```
std::map<std::reference_wrapper<const Object>, int, std::less<const Object>> table;
```

It will work correctly and as expected due to [implicit conversion of `std::reference_wrapper` to `T&`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper/get) and [implicit constructor of `std::reference_wrapper`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper/reference_wrapper).

[Example](https://godbolt.org/g/NJa8NL).

Answer (score 1):

On Visual Studio 11 Beta, I get the same problem.
Using the free version which calls the < operator solves the problem.

```
#include<map>
#include<iostream>
using namespace::std;

class Object { 
    int _n1;
public:

    Object(int n = 0):_n1(n){};
    bool operator < (const Object& rhs) const {return this->_n1 < rhs._n1;} 
    friend ostream &operator << (ostream &stream, const Object& o) { stream << o._n1 << " "; return stream;}
};

struct ObjectLess{

    bool operator()(const Object& lhs, const Object& rhs) const 
    {
        return lhs<rhs;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    //This does not compile
    //std::map<std::reference_wrapper<const Object>, string> table;

    //Using the free function works
    std::map<std::reference_wrapper<const Object>, string, ObjectLess> table;

    Object a(1);
    Object b(2);
    Object c(3);


    table[a]="One";
    table[c]="Three";
    table[b]="Two";

    for(auto y: table){
    cout << y.first << " " << y.second.c_str() << std::endl;
}


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I didn't get from a cursory look what's the purpose of `struct Objectless`, so I went forward and tried building it, to play a bit with the code. Well, it doesn't compile, I'm getting `/usr/include/c++/8.1.1/bits/stl_tree.h:452:21: error: static assertion failed: comparison object must be invocable with two arguments of key type
       static_assert(__is_invocable<_Compare&, const _Key&, const _Key&>{},`.