# Using an object reference as a key in std::unordered_map

Tags: c++, c++11, libstdc++, libc++

I'd like to know if it is possible to use an object reference as a key in an unordered_map container in C++.

```
#include <unordered_map>

class Object {
    int value;
};

struct object_hash {
  inline size_t operator()(const Object& o) const { return 0; }
};

std::unordered_map<Object&, int, object_hash> map;
```

When trying to compile this simple snippet, I got some errors about methods redefinition:

Using clang with libc++

> **/usr/include/c++/v1/unordered_map:352:12: error: class member cannot be redeclared**
>
> size_t operator()(const _Cp& __x) const

Using gcc 4.6 with libstdc++

> **/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/hashtable_policy.h:556:5:** error:
>   ‘std::__detail::_Map_base<_Key, _Pair, std::_Select1st<_Pair>, true,
>   _Hashtable>::mapped_type& std::__detail::_Map_base<_Key, _Pair, std::_Select1st<_Pair>, true, _Hashtable>::operator [with
>   _Key = Object&, _Pair = std::pair, _Hashtable = std::_Hashtable,
>   std::allocator >,
>   std::_Select1st >, std::equal_to,
>   object_hash, std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing,
>   std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash,
>   std::__detail::_Prime_rehash_policy, false, false, true>,
>   std::__detail::_Map_base<_Key, _Pair, std::_Select1st<_Pair>, true,
>   _Hashtable>::mapped_type = int]’ **cannot be overloaded**
>
> **/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/hashtable_policy.h:537:5**: error: **with**
>   ‘std::__detail::_Map_base<_Key, _Pair, std::_Select1st<_Pair>, true,
>   _Hashtable>::mapped_type& std::__detail::_Map_base<_Key, _Pair, std::_Select1st<_Pair>, true, _Hashtable>::operator[](const _Key&)
>   [with _Key = Object&, _Pair = std::pair, _Hashtable =
>   std::_Hashtable,
>   std::allocator >,
>   std::_Select1st >, std::equal_to,
>   object_hash, std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing,
>   std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash,
>   std::__detail::_Prime_rehash_policy, false, false, true>,
>   std::__detail::_Map_base<_Key, _Pair, std::_Select1st<_Pair>, true,
>   _Hashtable>::mapped_type = int]’

If I use an old gnu hash_map instead (__gnu_cxx::hash_map), I don't have this problem.

Is this some limitation imposed by the new standard, and if so, why?

Is there a way to workaround this limitation?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The new standard defines `std:reference_wrapper<T>` to work around this limitation.

It is implicitly convertible to a `T&` so that it is transparent, and like references guarantee there is no `null` state, however unlike references it can be re-seated.

More information in [Using `std::reference_wrapper` as key in `std::map`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9139748/using-stdreference-wrapper-as-the-key-in-a-stdmap).

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this and my colleagues helped me discover a solution that I thought was worth sharing:

```
struct RefWapperAddressHash
{
    std::size_t operator()( Object const& obj ) const
    {
        std::hash< Object const* > theHash{};
        return theHash( &obj );
    }
};

std::unordered_map< std::reference_wrapper< Object >, int, RefWrapperAddressHash > m_map;
```

This uses [std::hash's](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash) ctor : `template< class T > struct hash<T*>;`